# Allowing Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web to access a network folder or file

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2012

Anyone know how to get visual studio 2012 express for web to have the right to access a network file that I am able to access by navigating to `\\cpu001\folder1\file1.txt`?

I tried going to IIS 6 and clicking my website, and "Basic Settings", and "Connect As", and entering the credentials for my Administrator account that I'm logged into windows with (I'm not worried about security right now), and this worked for all but ONE of the computers on my network. One of them still can't be accessed through my code, even though I can access the file easily through windows by navigating to `\\cpu001\folder1\file1.txt`??

Is there a way to get visual studio / IIS to have access to this file? I have IIS 6 connecting as the same account that I'm logged into as administrator. It's accessing the other networked computers just fine through my code. I double checked that using the correct network path to the file, same one I use in windows to get to the file. I'm confused.

EDIT: I fixed it.

I had mapped the root folder of the path I was accessing for each computer. I wasn't using the mapped path in my code, I was using the \ paths. And as I said in my question, I was able to access all but one of my networked computers from my code. Well, I un-mapped the path to the computer that was giving me trouble, and re-mapped it. This is done in the "Computer" in windows 7, and you simply click the "Mapp network drive", with credentials to the admin account that I use on the computer my website is running on. ANYWAY after I re-mapped the drive, now my code can access the files. No idea why this worked.

But anyone else trying to access files through your code in visual studio 2012 for web: gotta give IIS admin permissions (though, it's a security risk, so anyone else is welcome to suggest a better idea), gotta map the path to (I guess to the root folder you need access to?), and gotta use the \ version of the path in your code, such as \cpu001\path\file.txt, and NOT the mapped folder path, such as: X:\path\file.txt, as that probably won't work.